# Can't connect to MySQL running in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, lamp, bitnami

I'm trying to build docker image with some legacy LAMP development stack for development purposes.
Basically I'm taking ubuntu image and installing bitnami LAMP stack.
Here's Dockerfile I have so far:

```
FROM ubuntu

EXPOSE 80 443 3306

WORKDIR /opt

COPY setup.sh .
RUN chmod +x setup.sh
RUN ./setup.sh      # this bash script downloads and runs installer

CMD /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start && tail -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/access_log
```

Then I'm running that container like this:

```
docker run --name dev -d -p 8080:80 -p 3307:3306 -v "C:\\dev\\project:/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs" aburov/lamp5.6
```

All works as expected (app from `c:\dev\project` is accessible throug `localhost:8080` and it can access database) except the fact tha I can't connect to MySQL from the host using mapped 3307 port.

I've tried connect from MySQL Workbench and JetBrains' DataGrip both failing with similar error:

> Communications link failure with primary. No active connection found for master.
> java.io.EOFException: unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server).

I've tried:

1. Using map to another host's port (3306, 3308, 10123) assuming there some conflicts;
2. Using different MySQL drivers.

MySQL version is 5.6.

What I'm missing?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you have to finetune yiur installer.sh, eve4rything needs his time to start and so you need to play around with pausing until the next step.

Comment: @nbk I would agree with you if it wouldn't work inside container, but it works. App is able to connect to database inside the container, but port doesn't seem to be published.
Also I'm not doing anything by hand, I'm just downloading and running installer from bitnami, which installs apache, php and mysq. And script which is starting services also comes from bitnami and correctly starts services one by one (what could be confirmed by logs).

Comment: docker works with a bridgem that maps the ports, so see what wireshark see in your docker when ysou try to connect, there should be a connection attempt. when te mappinhg fails it s quite hard to pinpoint the exact cause. Does the webserver  run and is accecible?

Comment: Yes, it's running and accessible from the host

Comment: so port 8080 ruzns and the webwser responds , mysql on port 3307 doesn't respond and you tested it with mysql client inside docker and did you install wireshrak and seen the pqackages that come from outside. what aöso ican think of check the my.cnf [mysqld]
bind-address=

Comment: @nbk you're right with your thoughts: the issue was in `bind-address` (then I had to update user priviledges to allow connecting from other hosts, but that was straightforward). Thanks! P.S. Feel free to leave and answer, so I can accept it

Comment: i added a andswer, you can also add what you have done additinal grating use access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking if the ports are mapped correctky and also verified da alocal mysqlclient can connect to the server, there is another possibiliry.

MySQL is in **default configuration** as security measure , only accepting access from the localhost.

So you have to control and change the following parameter in the `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld] 
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

That would allow access from **every**  ip

Additionally by default `root` has privileges for `localhost` only so it's not allowed to connect with that user from another hosts. To fix that we can execute following SQL commands from within container:

```sql
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Another option would be to create separate user (by runnin corresponding SQL from within container).

Comment: One more addition here: it turned out to be much easier and straightforward solution to use `docker-compose` and combining couple of existing images (php:5.6.34-apache, mysql:5.6). They created by corresponding teams and are ready to use, so I've spent way less time setting them up